# Question about Nehari manifold

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have two questions about the Nehari manifold, the first one is where i can found the properties of this manifold ?

and the second one is in a theorem it says "let M a Banach-finsler manifold" can we apply this theorem if we have a "Nehari manifold" ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can find an overview in a couple of papers by A. Szulkin (and see also the references therein): [here][1] and [here][2]. Your second question is totally unclear.


  [1]: http://www2.math.su.se/~andrzejs/Recent_publications/Nehari.pdf
  [2]: http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1740-08.pdf

Comment: Thank you, for the second quenstion i have this theorem  http://i.stack.imgur.com/xk8h6.png and i want to know if it still right for a Nehari manifold ? thank you

Comment: It depends on the regularity properties of your functional. In many cases, the Nehari manifold is a $C^1$ manifold, so that it is a Banach (or Hilbert) manifold.

Comment: @Siminore please can we introduce a Finsler manifold in a Hilbert space ?i.e can we say let $M\subset H$ where $M$ is a Finsler manifold and $H$ a Hilbert space ? thank you

Comment: I am not an expert, but I guess so. I read on Wikipedia that every Riemannian manifold is a Finsler manifold.